# Expect toNotBe() is undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

This code:

> expect(X).toNotBe(Y);

Returns me:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Jasmine version is 2.0.3

Do you know where should i look into?

Comment: `toNotBe` or `not.toBe`? That is the question.

Comment: @Barney Ah! I really LOLed at that one =P

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It should be:

```
expect(X).not.toBe(Y);
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use

```
expect(X).not.toBe(Y);
```

Read this [Jasmine introduction](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)